# Orientation of iphone video changes in browser Rails paperclip ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a application developed in ruby on rails.Created a video uploading functionality, am able to upload video to s3 successfully, but the issue i am facing is that video orientation of video file is getting changed. I am not converting video in background.Its the original video which is getting uploaded as it is. Quicktime player plays video in portrait orientation but when i upload it to s3  via paperclip (ffmpeg) my browser plays it in landscape orientation. I have no idea why it is happening, has anyone come across similar issue.(I did some research and found that video taken from apple mobile works correctly in quicktime player whereas other browsers play it in landscape).

Plugin:
I am using VIDEO JS plugin to play videos. 
(suggestions on video plugin which can play quicktime video perfectly with others video formats are also welcome).

Here is my video.rb code:

```
  validates_presence_of :video, :school_id, :user_id
  validates_attachment :video, presence: true

  has_attached_file :video, 
                path: ":folder_name/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                storage: :s3, 
                s3_host_name: PAPERCLIP_S3[:host_name], 
                bucket: PAPERCLIP_S3[:bucket], 
                s3_credentials: PAPERCLIP_S3[:credentials],                    
                :s3_permissions => :private,
                :styles => {
                  #:flv => { :geometry => "1024x576", :format => 'flv', :convert_options => {:output => {:ar => 44100}} },
                  :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 3 }
                }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]


   validates_attachment :video, content_type: {content_type: ['application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 'application/flv', 'video/x-flv', 'video/mp4', 'application/x-mp4', 'application/mp4', 'video/x-mp4','video/quicktime']}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Only quicktime can play portrait video recorded in iPhone correctly, players like VLC etc play the portrait mode videos in landscape because it is encoded that way! Maybe apple have set some bit so that quicktime identifies and sets the orientation properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the EXIF tags with something like the `mini_exiftool` gem, if I remember it's the `rotation` tag, that will tell you by how many degrees the video has to be rotated.

Then use that information to tell the player how it has to play it, or use a converter like `FFMpeg` to pre-rotate the video.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg that has support for automatic rotation, see commit: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg/commit/3e3670432378bd0648b4ffd51d3038f2a3f620f2 That will rotate your videos as they are uploaded.